# array's elements display on second render

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am using MapView and want to display some markers on the map. The list I receive with props arrives ok since I use console.log to check but the map is not updating when and keeps its old state. When I render for second time, then it gets updated. Why does this happen. The list array is received correctly but the MapView Component updates after second render. I dont how how can I make the component update when the list comes.

For example: When the list comes with 3 markers (using console.log) the maps displays 0 markers and after rendering again it shows 3 markers. The component is always one step behind

```
import { Image, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';


export default class MapComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


render() {

      console.log(this.props.list)

      let position=null
       position = this.props.list.map((maps, key) =>{
        var latitudine = parseFloat(maps.latitudine);
        var longitudine = parseFloat(maps.longitudine);
        return (
          <Marker key={key} coordinate={{ latitude: latitudine, longitude: longitudine }} cluster={true}>
            <Image source={require('../../../assets/png/posizione_mappa.png')} style={{ height: 60, width: 60 }} />
          </Marker>
        )
      }) 



      return (
           <View>
          <MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            clustering={true}
            clusterColor='#db432b'
            clusterTextColor='white'
            clusterBorderColor='#f29485'
            clusterBorderWidth={10}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            customMapStyle={mapStyle}
            showsMyLocationButton={false}
            style={styles.map}
          >
          {position}
          </MapView>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.props.list` empty at start (during data loading at parent) ? console.log lenght - rather parent problem

Answer (score 0):

This might be due the fact that your `list` prop reference is not being updated on change. e.g. if you have attached this data to component using redux `connect` then you need to so something like

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => (
  {
    list: [...state.someReducer.list]
  }
)
connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent);
```

Or if you are passing this prop from a parent component, make sure that data is not being mutated. Pass a new reference on each change in this list

Comment: Thank you for your response. the list I receive with props comes ok. I have updated the explanation to explain better my situation. Please have a look and see If you can help me.